# NginX with FastCGI and WordPress in a subdirectory - "No input file specified"

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to migrate a WordPress blog to a subdirectory of my website (i.e. example.com/blog/). Using NginX and FastCGI, I've managed to get the entire WordPress site working on port 8080, but as soon as I attempt to apply rules to place it in /blog, I get "No input file specified"

I think because I can get PHP and WordPress working, I can assume that there are no issues with my installation or the permissions of the relevant folders.

This is what my virtual host looks like (I am running a rails site at "/"):

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location /blog/ {
        root /home/deploy/www/blog.example.com/html;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /home/deploy/www/blog.example.com/html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location / {
        root   /home/deploy/www/example.com/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

I have also tried this configuration for the same result:

```
    location ~ ^/blog/.*(\.php)?$ {
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
           root   /home/deploy/www/blog.example.com/html;
           try_files $uri =404;
    #        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/.+\.php)(.*)$;

            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having any luck? I'm facing issues with a subdirectory install where WP has some of its urls incorrectly pointing to root

Comment: Maybe "C" is not defined in php.ini variables_order directive? What phpinfo() shows? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WordPress with Multisite?

I am not clear about your setup, but a tutorial from this list will surely help you: http://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorial

If you can share more details, I can guide you better.

From where does 8080 coming into picture? R u using Nginx with Apache??

"No input file specified" looks like an error related to incorrect location of PHP file...

Try changing

`enter code here`fastcgi_index index.php;

to

```
try_files index.php blog/index.php
```

Assuming 'blog' is a folder where you moved your WordPress.